# Deploying a "working when run locally via pycharm" django app to webfaction

Tags: django, web-deployment, webfaction

I've been following the steps in the box under "Configuring Django" [here](https://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html) to try and get the django app up onto webfaction after getting it to work locally.

I zipped my project folder and used scp myproject.zip `catubc@web513.webfaction.com` to get it up. I then used ssh and moved the zip to `$HOME/webapps/plot_composite_metrics` as the linked steps instruct and unzipped it there. Since the name of my project is "myproject" I didn't have to do steps 6-7.

From the webfaction control panel I have made an application and called it `plot_composite_metrics`, Django 1.9.1 (mod_wsgi 4.4.21/Python 2.7). I also made a new website called `good_morning_cat` and added `plot_composite_metrics` to it.

I have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['catubc.webfactional.com']` in `settings.py`

So, as per [this example](https://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/examples.html) why do I get a "server not found" when I navigate to http://good_morning_cat.catubc.webfactional.com/? What did I forget to do to link my working-locally via pycharm app to said domain?

I have seen [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795356/deploying-django-project-on-webfaction), sadly I believe I am using the correct python version, so that's not the issue. Additionally, I do have a paid account if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all the domains in the WebFaction control panel, i e http://**good_morning_cat**.catubc.webfactional.com/ as well.

http://catubc.webfactional.com/ works as this is what you have specified, it's resolved anyway. There's an `ImportError` because you haven't installed all your dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand. import matplotlib.cbook as cbook -->> Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'cbook'. But this code is in "/home/catubc/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py" which I didn't write. Also matplotlib 1.4.3 "is already the active version in easy_install.pth" so how do I install this dependency?